# Can't boot Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview

When I try to boot Windows 8, it starts automatic repair process which fails to repair it. It logs stuff in c:\windows\system32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt. After one of attempted automatic repairs, last line in that file said that **tm.sys and clfs.sys files are corrupt** (current version says "Startup Repair has tried several times but still cannot determine the cause of the problem.")

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have not tried this on W8, boot from the W8 install media and choose "repair your computer" to load the tools, then [follow this guide to run a sfc offline](http://mikemstech.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-perform-offline-system-integrity.html)

Comment: I ended up reinstalling windows, nothing else would help. I also found some corrupt files afterwords...

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  PC started acting real slow and I hit the reset button.  Afterward the system failed to boot properly.  Pathetic how fragile the windows bootloader is.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go about this is reinstalling windows 8 and by the tag I'll guess it's 8.1

This should help for future reference and anybody else.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-download